# transformation of nested array in array by jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have following JSON data . I want to transform following data by Jolt nifi processor into result data

```json
{
  "alert_array": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "alertId": "alt001",
        "severity": "High",
        "alert_type": "Alert"
      },
      {
        "alertId": "alt002",
        "severity": "High",
        "alert_type": "Alert"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

result data

```json
{
  "alert_array": [
    {
      "Id": "alt001",
      "speed": "High",
      "type": "Alert"
    },
    {
      "Id": "alt002",
      "speed": "High",
      "type": "Alert"
    }
  ]
}
```

please help to write spac of jolt transformation

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't rename the attributes, then using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&]"  // &2 represents going two levels up to get the literal "alert_array"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

would suffice.

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

But in your case, you need to qualify each one individually such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "alert*": "&3[&1].&(0,1)",
            "severity": "&3[&1].speed",
            "alert_*": "&3[&1].&(0,1)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]